# Request JSON within a loop

Tags: node.js, object, request

I'm having trouble to surf correctly between objects that are been returned by an API request.

Basically, I have an Array (`tickerArr` with 25 elements that I get from another request) which I use for a `forEach` loop for another request.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs')

var getTickerList = require('./getTickerList').getTickerList;
var unixTimeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

async function getTickerInfo() {

  var tickerArr = await getTickerList;
  var arrLength = tickerArr.length;
  var init = 0;

  console.log(`${arrLength} to process to the batchfile...`);
  var getTickerInfo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async.forEach(tickerArr, (item, callback) => {
      request({
        url:`https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=${item}`,
        json: true
      }, (error, response, body) => {
        var tickerInfo = JSON.stringify(body.result)
        fs.appendFile(`./modules/batches/${unixTimeStamp}batch.json`, tickerInfo, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          init ++;
          var progress = Math.round(init / arrLength * 100);
          console.log(`[${progress}%] - ${item} successfully added!`);
        });
         resolve();
      })
    });
  });
}

getTickerInfo()
```

Unfortunately, and even if the request works correctly, the objects being returned have a specific path:

> - Error: []
> - Result:
>
>   - Pair(x):
>
>     - a: [1, 2, 3]
>     - b: [1, 2, 3] ect...

You can find an exact example of the information being returned from the request [here](https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=xxbtzeur):

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "XXBTZEUR": {
            "a": ["2212.31000", "3", "3.000"],
            "b": ["2212.21100", "1", "1.000"],
            "c": ["2212.31000", "0.15800000"],
            "v": ["4999.06419498", "9993.55448658"],
            "p": ["2206.04624", "2181.36028"],
            "t": [15065, 29524],
            "l": ["2167.00000", "2122.92000"],
            "h": ["2239.00000", "2239.00000"],
            "o": "2184.99000"
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is: I would like to 'transform' the object I get from the request, to another object (just arranging stuff around, most of all: put the 'Pair(x)' attribute as a value for a name key) but since I don't know the pair in advance (the values in my `tickerArray` are enough to make the request but do not apparently correspond to reference the object), I can't access the information contained within result to manipulate it.

Anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tomalak!

Comment: No problem. The "let's call it JSON" mistake happens very often. General rule: JSON is a *string*. If you are not talking about strings, you are not talking about JSON.

Comment: For starters, is there a special reason why you are not using `request-promise`?

Comment: I'll try to get a little more into it... I was sure to be dealing with strings here: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=xxbtzeur! 
My bad, :S Noob coming through!

Comment: You are, but only for the sake of the transport over the wire. They are decoded into plain JS objects and at that point they stop being JSON.

Comment: OK! As for the request-promise: again "Noob coming through" I got confortable using request for the moment so that's what I used... I noticed the request-promise library and thought about using it but I wanted to get the whole thing working first. Would you rather have me use it right now?

Comment: The `async` keyword in JS means "this function returns a promise". And instead of building your own promise (`new Promise(...)`) and dealing with all the callback business, it's sensible to use the promise-enabled version of the library right from the start. This saves a lot of typing and it prevents mistakes that easily happen in code that connects callback-based APIs with promise-based APIs.

Comment: You have the object after you request it. You can use [`Object.keys(body.result)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array with all the root-keys (`["XXBTZEUR"]` for your example). Or loop over the object directly with `for (let key in body.result) { ...}`.  Maybe post an example of how you want your data to look like in the end.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks for the clarification, I thought that async meant asynchronous which will therefore need a callback function. I guess that a promise and a callback are pretty much the same but I understood that the structure was different: a callback returns a result at the end while a promise facilitates chaining functions together and simply gets resolved (certainly less code than the callback). In my case, I could use the request-promise lib. but I want to use the forEach function and I'm not sure how to chain the 2... Thanks a lot for your clarifications and patience!

Comment: @RoyalBingBong: I'll try this ASAP and let you know but it seems like the solution. I actually thought of the Array conversion but was not sure how to implement it... (still unsure but I guess that by studying your answer a little more I'll get it!). Thanks!

Comment: We could help you more if you could also give us an example of how the data should look like in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has multiple levels and maybe it's best to break up the task into its constituent parts first.

1. Calling the Kraken REST API and unwrapping the response
2. Creating small, composable functions
3. Transforming an object into a new layout
4. Writing the results to a file

## 0. Preface

Since you want to work with `await`, the first thing to know is that this is syntactical sugar for "wait for promise resolution". `async` is the keyword that enables `await` semantics inside a function.

So given this promise-returning function:

```
function foo() {
    return Promise.resolve('some value');
}
```

this:

```
async function worker() {
    var fooResult = await foo();
    console.log(fooResult);
}
worker();
```

and this:

```
foo().then(function worker(fooResult) {
    console.log(fooResult);
});
```

are effectively the same thing. (As always, it's a little more complicated than that, but that's the gist of it.)

Since we are working with promises here, the most sensible thing to do is to use libraries that also use promises. `request` has the `request-promise` counter-part, so let's use that.

```
var request = require('request-promise');
```

## 1. Calling the Kraken REST API and unwrapping the response

Making an HTTP request and breaking up the response (`err` and `result` parts) works the same for all API endpoints, so we can write a function that handles this task.

```
function getFromApi(endpoint, params) {
    return request({
        url: "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/" + endpoint,
        qs: params,
        json: true
    }).then(function (data) {
        if (data.error && data.error.length) {
            throw new Error(`API error xyz for ${endpoint} with params ...`);
        }
        return data.result;
    });
}
```

Users of this function will not have to deal with `err` at all and have access to `result` directly.

## 2. Creating small, composable functions

Our `getFromApi()` function returns a promise, therefore we can re-use it in wrappers for various API endpoints:

```
function getTickerList() {
    return getFromApi("TickerList"); // ...or something like that
}

function getSingleTicker(pair) {
    return getFromApi("Ticker", {pair: pair}).then(transformTicker);
}

function getTickerInfo(tickerList) {
    return Promise.all(tickerList.map(getSingleTicker));
}
```

Note that, like in `getFromApi()`, we can use `Promise#then` to modify the overall output of an operation.

`getTickerInfo()` accepts an array of ticker names. It uses `Array#map` to run all API requests in parallel, and `Promise#all` to allow awaiting the overall result. The fairly complex operation of fetching and transforming multiple results in parallel composes into a pretty straight-forward one-liner.

## 3. Transforming an object into a new layout

`transformTicker()` is meant to accept an object in form `{"XXBTZEUR": {"a": [...], ... }}` and return a transformed variant of it.

```
function transformTicker(ticker) {
  var result = {};

  // ...massage ticker into desired form
  Object.keys(ticker).forEach( pair => {
      Object.keys(ticker[pair]).forEach( k => {
          result[k] = { /* ... */ };
      });
  });

  return result;
}
```

## 4. Writing the results to a file

Appending to a JSON file does not work. JSON can only be read and written as a whole. Let's fetch a list of ticker names, the associated tickers and write the results to a file.

```
async function worker() {
    var tickerList = await getTickerList();
    var tickerInfo = await getTickerInfo(tickerList);
    var filename = `./modules/batches/${new Date().toISOString()}batch.json`;

    fs.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(tickerInfo), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Done");
    });
}

worker();
```

You can switch use a promisified version ([see `Bluebird#promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html)) of the `fs` module, since the plain version breaks the nice async/await semantics again by requiring a continuation callback.

With a promisified `fs` module, the worker could look like this:

```
async function worker() {
    var tickerList = await getTickerList();
    var tickerInfo = await getTickerInfo(tickerList);
    var filename = `./modules/batches/${new Date().toISOString()}batch.json`;

    await fs.writeFileAsync(filename, JSON.stringify(tickerInfo));
    console.log("Done");
}
```

Comment: Oh my god Tomalak you're the best! Thanks I'll get into it ASAP and hope I'll make you proud!!! Thanks again !

Comment: Disclaimer: Normally I post only tested code in answers. I did not test this code, as I was putting more emphasis on the general approach itself (and because I did not want to spend time learning the Kraken API). It's entirely possible that there's an oversight or syntax error in there. If you find something that's not quite right, ping me and I will correct it.

Comment: Definitely besides I usually prefer this approach (the general one) to learn correctly (teach me how to fish rather than give me one) but I know that it is usually time consuming to answer in this fashion si thanks again!

Comment: @Ardzii Of course I had to mess it up. See updated answer.

Comment: Hey @Tomalak! Thanks again, I have been working on it and the structure is much clearer like that. I especially like the `Promise.all` function, brilliant. I'm having some issues with the getSingleTicker function though... For some reason (I'm putting a `console.log` in there to make some test) nothing returns to the screen. I have decided to put every function (getSingleTicker, getTickerList and getTickerInfo) in separate modules...(I require the module in each step) maybe that's what messing with the process... I might have to put everything together as suggested in your answer? Thanks!!!

Comment: Hint: The `.then()` callback function needs to return a value. Your module layout won't be problematic in this regard.

Comment: That's what I got... the getSingleTicker function calls the getFromApi module which for the sake of the example I'm setting to a specific pair (XXBTZEUR): `getFromApi('Ticker', {pair: 'XXBTZEUR'}).then((data) => { console.log(data); }).catch((err) => { console.log('Failed', err); )};` but nothing shows up (no error, no nothing...). The getFromApi module works properly though (I've test it with an example. It finishes with `return data.result;`)... In case you have time to give it a quick look, here's the github: https://github.com/Ardzii/mongoNode. Thanks a million for everything anyhow!

Comment: Your code works for me. The only thing I noticed is that the API does not return an `err` property, but an `error` property. I take it that you have fixed that.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the heads up regarding the error. How come the code works with you and I get nothing on my end? I'll reboot see what happens...

Comment: Still no luck... I don't really get how it works for you and not for me. That' weird and a bit frustrating :P

Comment: Hey @Tomalak! Thanks again, it finally worked... I was (as usual) just being dumb. I'm trying to crunch through a variable exports (getTickerList) that doesn't seem to be exporting properly (it returns undefined).

Comment: I suspected something like this. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Hey Tomalak! If you have a second could you check what is happening with the file writting portion of the code...? I'm getting [null,null,null...] when I know from a fact that the result is being correctly changed to adapt to my new layout. Plus if I put result = ticker it writes the file with all the information (not in the correct layout but still). Sorry again to bother you... https://github.com/Ardzii/mongoNode

Comment: I appreciate that you are happy I could help you, but I cannot be your interactive guide. The question as you have asked it is answered and I followed up quite a bit, but I can't keep doing that indefinitely. Please, reduce your case to an [mcve] and ask a new question if you can't figure it out yourself. That's how Stack Overflow works. :)

Comment: Thanks a million Tomalak! I've been abusing of your kindness and I understand perfectly! I'm a bit new with SO. So thanks again for your help and understanding! Have a good day and hope to see you around --> on a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable new question ;) ! Really, really thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. You've got the right spirit, keep it up. :)